# Get IDs of elements with given attribute and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the ids of all elements, which have both the attribute `data-test` and the class `myClass`.

So in this case that would be only `elem3`, as it is the only element to meet both criteria:

```
<input type="text" data-test="someValue" id="elem1" />
<input type="text" class="myClass" id="elem2" />
<input type="text" class="myClass" data-test="someValue" id="elem3" />
```

With

```
$('input[data-test], .myClass').attr("id")
```

I only get `elem1`, instead of `elem3`.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoLfe04a/).

Comment: `$('input[data-test].myClass').attr("id")`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aoLfe04a/6/

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla simple & sober solution, meets the requirement perfectly +1

Answer (score 1):

To get all elements use  `$.each`.This will loop through all DOM objects

```
$.each($('input[data-test].myClass'), function() {
    alert( this.id );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aoLfe04a/8/

Comment: This gives me all elements.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery attr() returns the attribute value of the first element.

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

Use .each to enumerate the ids:

```
$('input[data-test], .myClass')
.each(function (i, el) { console.log($(el).attr("id"))})
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoLfe04a/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be like this:

`$('input[data-test][class=myClass]').attr("id")`

[Fiddle for Single](https://jsfiddle.net/aoLfe04a/1/)

To get list of all elements you need to use `$.each` like this:

```
 $.each($('input[data-test][class=myClass]'), function() {
    console.log( this.id );
 });
```

[Fiddle for all Elements](https://jsfiddle.net/aoLfe04a/5/)

Reference: [Multiple Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Comment: But how can I get all of them, not only the 1st one?

Comment: @user1170330 you can use `$.each` to get all elements

Comment: Also acceptable: `$("input.myClass[data-test]").attr("id")`

Or, since you didn't mention the element necessarily being an input in the requirements (although it is implied), you could also use: `$(".myClass[data-test]").attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('input.myClass[data-test]').map(function(){
  return  this.id
});
```

will give array of ids

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

If your goal is to find a single element that has both the data-test attribute and the myClass class, you should change your script from this...

```
$('input[data-test], .myClass').attr("id")
```

...to this...

```
$('input[data-test].myClass').attr("id")
```

**Explanation**

Giving two conditions separated by a comma means you will get everything that meets *either* of those conditions. In this case that's all three elements. The reason you're only seeing elem1 is because calling `.attr("id")` on an array returns only the id of the first element.

Pushing the input and class selectors together as in my slightly-revised line of code only return elements that meet both conditions.

**Additional**

If it is possible that you will return multiple elements, and you would like an array of their ids, you will have to save `$('input[data-test], .myClass').attr("id")` into a variable, check it's length, and then iterate through it if there are multiple hits. Because I do not believe this is your question, I'm not going to elaborate further (but I believe other respondents already have).

**Reference Material**

[jQuery Selectors Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery Loop like this .

```
$.each($('input[data-test], .myClass'), function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    alert(this.id);
});
```